# Top Right Menu Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user, dropdown, settings, menu

I don't know how it happened but now, when I click the top right gear icon, or my name, instead of a drop down, I get an incomplete pop up window with the hyperlinks that should have appeared on the drop down menu. Please help!

Addition: all call-out / fly-out menus behave the same, on click I get a pop up window with a part of the options.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Close all internet explorer windows. Make sure iexlplorer.exe is not running and reopen the application.